# How to use the vegaEmbed function inside a loop passing element ids dynamically generated through a v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vega-lite

I'm using Vega-Lite with VueJs and I need to dynamically render a list of charts generated after a user action.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div v-for="(chart, index) in possibleCharts" :key="index" :id="'chart'+index"></div>
```

And in the JavaScript side, I have something like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i<possibleCharts.length; i++){
    vegaEmbed("#chart"+i, possibleCharts[i].spec);
}
```

But rendering does not happen because the DOM elements are dynamically generated and apparently this does not work that way... Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It should be `this.possibleCharts` instead of `possibleCharts`
- If `possibleCharts` is load asynchronously, you should watch this value and render after that using `$nextTick`. Thanks.

> ```
> watch: {
>   possibleCharts() {
>     this.$nextTick(() => {
>       for (let i = 0; i < this.possibleCharts.length; i++) {
>         vegaEmbed("#chart" + i, this.possibleCharts[i].spec);
>       }
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```

Hope this will help.